# Want to combine the functions of two PHP Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I want a function, such that users should download a pdf or access a link after a countdown. Plus Users should be logged in, if they are not logged in they should be redirect to the login page (slug = "/login")

I have two working code for both "Login to Download" Redirection function and the "Count Down" Function.

The Code are :

1. Login to Download Code :

```
function um_login_to_download( $atts ) {
  //shortcode attributes
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'url' => '',
    'label' => '',
    'class' => '', // Added 'class' attribute for custom CSS classes
  ), $atts));

  //check if user is logged in
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //if logged in, display the download link with the specified label and custom CSS class
    return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="'.$class.'">'.$label.'</a>';
  } else {
    //if not logged in, display a login link with the label "Login to Download" that redirects to Ultimate Member login page and custom CSS class
    $redirect_url = get_permalink();
    return '<a href="/login/?redirect_to='.$redirect_url.'" class="'.$class.'">Login to Download</a>';
  }
}

//add shortcode for login to download
add_shortcode( 'login_to_download', 'um_login_to_download' );
```

2. Countdown Code :

```
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php or a code snippet plugin

function countdown_button_shortcode($atts) {
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(array(
        'minutes' => 5,
        'seconds' => 0,
    ), $atts);

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    ob_start(); ?>

    <div id="countdown-timer">
        <button id="download-button" disabled>Wait <?php echo $attributes['minutes']; ?> min <?php echo $attributes['seconds']; ?> sec to Download the PDF</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var targetTime = new Date();
            targetTime.setMinutes(targetTime.getMinutes() + <?php echo $attributes['minutes']; ?>);
            targetTime.setSeconds(targetTime.getSeconds() + <?php echo $attributes['seconds']; ?>);

            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var currentTime = new Date();
                var timeRemaining = targetTime - currentTime;

                if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $('#download-button').text('Download the PDF').prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    var minutes = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                    var seconds = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                    $('#download-button').html('Wait ' + minutes + ' min ' + seconds + ' sec to Download the PDF');
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>

    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('countdown_button', 'countdown_button_shortcode');
```

The above two PHP code are working Properly, But I want both the function in One place. Such that When a Non-Logged in user visit the page, First the Count-down should be show, then The Button with "Login to Download" Should be show.

These function works with short code, and the final short code after combining these two code should be like : [login_to_download countdown_button minutes="10" seconds="30" url="https://example.com/download.pdf"  label=”Download” class=”download-button”]

where class="download-button" is to style the button

I have tried a lot, but did't get the right solution. recently i have used this :

```
function um_login_to_download( $atts ) {
  // Shortcode attributes
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'url' => '',
    'label' => '',
    'class' => '', // Added 'class' attribute for custom CSS classes
    'countdown' => 10, // Set the default countdown time (in seconds)
  ), $atts));

  // Check if user is logged in
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // If logged in, display the download link with the specified label and custom CSS class
    return '<a href="'.$url.'" class="'.$class.'">'.$label.'</a>';
  } else {
    // If not logged in, display the countdown and JavaScript code
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div id="countdown-container">
      <button id="countdown-button" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">Wait <span id="countdown"><?php echo $countdown; ?></span> sec to Download</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      // JavaScript countdown logic
      var countdown = <?php echo $countdown; ?>;
      var countdownButton = document.getElementById("countdown-button");
      var countdownSpan = document.getElementById("countdown");

      function updateCountdown() {
        countdown--;
        countdownSpan.innerText = countdown;
        if (countdown <= 0) {
          clearInterval(countdownInterval); // Stop the countdown
          countdownButton.innerHTML = '<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></a>';
        }
      }

      var countdownInterval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
  }
}

// Add shortcode for login to download
add_shortcode( 'login_to_download', 'um_login_to_download' );
```

But It did't worked.

I want to merge the Function of both the PHP Code into one.

Comment: `First the Count-down should be show, then The Button with "Login to Download" Should be show`...why? I think, if you know the user is not logged in (which you'll be able to tell immediately when you're loading the page), then you should not waste their time with a countdown before telling them to log in. Consider the user experience...the user does not want to wait, only to find out that they must log in, and then repeat the waiting. just redirect them to log in as soon as they hit that URL. Send them back to that page again after logging in, and then show your countdown.

Comment: Clarify what is not working.

Comment: P.S. "didn't work" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't fix "didn't work" in code, like a mechanic can't fix a car that "didn't work" without any other info about the problem. How isn't it working? What [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have you done? What exactly happens when you run this? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc. See also [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @nageen I don't think that's the issue with this post. The amount of code is pretty reasonable and largely relevant. What's missing is any meaningful explanation of the problem when they run the combined code.

Comment: I have a working code for "Login to Download" function, that is a user must login to download any PDF. Plus I want users should read the article for certain time (countdown), then they can download the PDF. As you mention above is also a great option, first redirect to login page and then show the countdown. But I want to merge this two function into one button, Mean first user will click "Login to download" button, then redirect to login page, after return he should wait for countdown, then he should download the PDF. If the user is already login he should only wait for the countdown.

Comment: Ok. Well it looks like the last version of the code you've shown in your question ought to implement that process already. So what exact problem are you having with it?

Comment: @ADyson Actually, I'm a beginner in coding. When I tried to add this two function into one PHP code, It sometimes shows the countdown only and sometime Just worked as "Login to download" function. The main intention behind this code is to gain the email ID of users, and to make them wait (read the article completely) to download the PDF. The two code are working correctly in separate, But I don't know how to implement them together. I think this 2 function should come 1 after another. When I tried, the countdown is shown in one button, but after that, logged out user are also able to download.

Comment: `sometimes `...in what circumstances, precisely? Remember we can't run your code, so you'll need to debug it pretty thoroughly and narrow down the problem to something more specific, if the issue isn't immediately visible just from viewing the code.

Comment: `logged out user are also able to download`...well the comment in your code says `// If not logged in, display the countdown and JavaScript code`...and then does exactly that. So maybe you wanted to move that code into the `if` where the user _is_ logged in? And in the not-logged-in `else` code, you probably want to redirect them to the login page instead.

Comment: I have tried to add this two functions many times, to work together. I am just trying that, the users should see the "Login to download" Button if not logged in. and if Logged in it should appear with the countdown. and after countdown the download link will appear. The two code are working fine separately, But when trying to show both "Login to Download" text and the "Countdown" in one Button, one after the another, I getting fail always.

Comment: You're mostly just repeating yourself and not really engaging with what I'm saying.

Comment: `the users should see the "Login to download" Button if not logged in`...so put something in your `else` code which displays that, then, instead of the countdown code.